# Html scroll and drag depends of the

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know if it's possible doing drag & drop in an item when the movement (touching) is vertical and scroll when is horizontally using the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/wj4ak/5/“.
In the div I have images, so I need that if I scroll Horizontal (On mobile) show all images, and if touch a image and move vertical move to other div.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="origin" class="fbox">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" id="one" title="one" class="draggable" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" id="two" title="two" class="draggable" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x100" id="three" title="three" />
    </div>
  <p>test</p>
```

css:

```
#origin
{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 120px;
}

#origin img, #drop img {
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#drop
{
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 120px;
}
.over {
  border: solid 5px purple;
}
.draggable
{
  border: solid 2px gray;
}
```

javascript

```
$("#origin").sortable({connectWith: "#drop"});

$("#drop").sortable({connectWith: "#origin"});
```